# elasticsearch cannot start up

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, docker

I am using Docker for the magento.
when I try fin project up
the elasticsearch looks likes like it can be startup, but when I check the status.
it is offline, any recommendation that I can get it fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably increase your max_map_count Kernel Parameter on Linux.
I faced the same issue, and the following solution helped me.

Try running this in your terminal:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

If it's not helping try to reload config as root using:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

And after that try to run your container with elasticsearch again.